# Putting Quotes to each string of a line

Tags: python

I am just trying to put quotes to each string in a line (I have a file with lines like this and look like):

`dog, monkey, elephant`
`monkey, dog, cat`
`fish, bird`

and I want to make it like this(put each string in a quote):

`'dog', 'monkey', 'elephant'`
`'monkey', 'dog', 'cat'`
`'fish', 'bird'`

Comment: Could you provide more context, why do you want that, and where's that `set` coming from?

Comment: You are creating a new variable called `str`, while trying to access `str.join()`. That can never go well.

Comment: Post the full error message. I have the impression is not related at all to the `sets = (...` line. Did you defined `ABC`, `DEF`, etc?

Comment: `set=[{ABC, DEF, GSF}, {ABC, ADF, TRS}, {DEF, GSF, BGH}]` is invalid as long as all the elements `ABC` et al are not defined, in which case they will be names. This is clearly XY problem.

Comment: You are shadowing a bunch of python built-ins. Aside from your code having reference issues, you are breaking python. Also, what you are calling a `set` of `lists` is actually a `list` of `sets`.

Comment: What is this `set=[{ABC, DEF, GSF}, {ABC, ADF, TRS}, {DEF, GSF, BGH}]`? Are `ABC`, `DEF`, etc variables that are defined? If not, it's nonsense.

Comment: The *values* in the set don't remember (in fact, never new) the names of the variables used to supply them, if that's what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be accomplished with something like this (making a few assumptions about your program):

```py
with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(', '.join(f'\'{a}\'' for a in line.rstrip('\n\r').split(', ')))
```

Comment: `f'\'{a}\''` is an overcomplicated way to write `f"'{a}'"`.

Answer (score 0):

please not that text values need to be in quotes, otherwise pythin cannot see the difference to a variable name.

try this

```
S1 = set(["abc"])
S2 = set(["efg"])
sets = [S1, S2]

result = [[f"'{v}'" for v in S] S for S in sets]

print(result)
```